# Running a remote command through an SSH Tunnel

Tags: macos, windows-xp, ssh, virtual-machine, proxy

I am trying to set up an ssh tunnel on my Mac OSX ('osx') to a server ('target') via an interim host ('gateway').  This tunnel needs to have a local (osx) port forward so that my Windows XP VM ('vm') can tunnel traffic through it (using proxifier).  So ultimately it will be:

```
vm -> osx -> gateway -> target
```

I can achieve this successfully using this command line on osx:

```
ssh -p 7002 -L 7777:localhost:6677 -t manachi@gateway.tld sh ./tunnel.sh target.tld;;
```

where tunnel.sh is a script on the remote gateway with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/ssh -i ~manachi/.ssh/my.id -p 7002 -D 6677 manachi@${1}
```

But I've been trying to set this up in my ~/.ssh/config on my osx (so that i can just type '**ssh target**') but am not having much luck.  My vm seems to be unable to tunnel via the osx tunnel.  Here is the config entry:

```
host target
HostName target.tld
Port 7002
User manachi
LocalForward 0:7777 localhost:6677
ProxyCommand ssh gateway nc %h %p
```

I'm not sure if I'm going about this all wrong. I'm not sure if the LocalForward is set up correctly, or if I can use 'nc' in ProxyCommand like that as a replacement for the remote 'ssh' command in the first solution, but any help or tips would be appreciated.

Comment: You had it right in your command lines. You're not going to type `ssh target`, you're going to type `ssh gateway` and your osx config file needs to have an entry for `gateway`, not `target`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much tweaking and experimenting and logging, I managed to get this tunnel working end-to-end by changing the line:

```
LocalForward 0:7777 localhost:6677
```

to

```
DynamicForward 0:7777
```

So final config entry looks like:

```
host target
HostName target.tld
Port 7002
User manachi
DynamicForward 0:7777
ProxyCommand ssh gateway nc %h %p
```

Now I can just type

```
ssh target
```

And then on my XP Virtual Machine I can point my Proxifier to my macosxhost:7777 and all working perfectly!